# Gradle cannot find Spring Boot 3.0.0-M1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle, dependencies

I'm not sure how to debug this or what is wrong at all. I am trying to run this project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login

In the project, Spring Boot 3.0.0-M1 is used to show the latest possibilities of JWT authentication. However, my Gradle cannot find this Spring Boot version no matter what I do. When I set it to 2.6.6 it works again, but it doesn't seem to be able to find 3.0.0-M1.

When I try to sync the dependencies I get the following error:

```
Build file 'C:\my files\general\subjects\programming\Open-source\spring-security-samples\servlet\spring-boot\java\jwt\login\build.gradle' line: 2

Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '3.0.0-M1'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

The Gradle configuration is as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0-M1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `settings.gradle` file? It’s in there that repositories for plugins are configured.

Comment: Change the order of repositories in your setup.. Put the milestone repository of spring first and central afterwards ... The spring SNAPSHOT repository should be remove except you are really working with SNAPSHOT versions?

Comment: @khmarbaise Changing the order of the repositories did not fix anything.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson It turns out the empty settings.gradle in the project was the reason it wouldn't load. See my answer below for what I had to add to it

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix it by downloading a 3.0.0-M2 project from Spring Initializr and seeing what differs between the example I got from the Spring Security examples repository and the generated project from Spring Initializr.

It turns out that adding the following to settings.gradle fixes it:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

I am not sure why the example project didn't have this already.